# Webcam broadcasts upside down

Tags: webcam

When I try to facebook video chat my image is broadcast upside down. Asus U81A-RX05 laptop with trusty tahr. It displays correctly in cheese. I tried getting libv4* but I can't find any of them in the repository and all the forums I looked at concerning this matter point me to a package that is not found in the ubuntu repository.Tried libv4-0 libv41 libv4l2. I see them on other websites but I do not know how where to save them or if I can use the apt command to download from a third party repository. Is there a more current version of videos4linux cause I'm not finding it anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

libv4-0 libv41 libv4l2 packages are found in Ubuntu's Trusty repositories as in here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libv4l-0.

You can download them from there and install them with Ubuntu Software Center, or Synaptic, or gdebi  (make sure you download the correct packages: x86-type, amd64-type, etc - same type as your ubuntu)

OR

you can open a Terminal window and type:

`sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libv4-0 libv41 libv4l2`